# DAX: Calculated Column with Multiple Tables Filter

Tags: excel, powerpivot, calculated-columns, dax

This relates to adding a Calculated Column to a table which fetches rows from two other tables based on some criteria.

Consider a model like this:

[image]

I want to come up with a Calculated Column called 'Budget Material Consumption' in the table 'Actual Material Utilization'. This should calculate how much the material should have been utilized in order to produce the products sold as per the standard Recipe table.

I wanted to use the following formula but its not working:

```
=Calculate( Sum(Recipe[RM_QTY]) * Sum(Sales[Qty]) , Filter(Recipe, Recipe[RM_ID]=Utilization[RM_ID]) , Filter(Sales,Sales[Product_ID]=Recipe[Product_ID]) )
```

Hope I am able to explain my query just fine.

Regards.

Comment: I wanted to use the following formula but its not working:
=Calculate( Sum(Recipe[RM_QTY]) * Sum(Sales[Qty]) , 
 Filter(Recipe, Recipe[RM_ID]=Utilization[RM_ID]) 
 , 
 Filter(Sales,Sales[Product_ID]=Recipe[Product_ID]) 
 )